# How to change localization on the fly SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

How can I change the localization of the App on the fly in SwiftUI?

I think we can use below code, but we should find SwiftUI approach.

```
func localized(_ lang:String) -> String {

    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: lang, ofType: "lproj")
    let bundle = Bundle(path: path!)

    return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: bundle!, value: "", comment: "")
}}
```

Answer (score 8):

First of all, we should create 2 `Localizable.strings` files, in my case it's ***en*** and ***ru***.

And we should store our current language object, I choose store it property in `UserSettings` like `ObservableObject`, We can also use `@AppStorage` when initializing the `lang` variable to keep the chosen language

```
class UserSettings: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var lang: String = "ru"
    
    var bundle: Bundle? {
        let b = Bundle.main.path(forResource: lang, ofType: "lproj")!
        return Bundle(path: b)
    }
}
```

We can use this settings object like `.environmentObject()` in `SceneDelegate.swift`, so every view in hierarchy will be updated.

```
var settings = UserSettings()
// ...
= UIHostingController(rootView: contentView.environmentObject(settings))
```

In `View` we can get desirable behaviour, note we should specify `bundle` in `Text` initialization.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var settings: UserSettings
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("App", bundle: settings.bundle)
        }
    }
}
```

And now I can change the language on someplace in the app, here is just sample *loop* example, you can call this function `changeLanguage()` in the of `scene(_ scene:, willConnectTo:, options connectionOptions:)` and every 3 seconds language will be changed.

```
func changeLanguage() {
    print(#function)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
        self.settings.lang = self.settings.lang == "ru" ? "en" : "ru"
        self.changeLanguage()
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't use "bundle:" inside Text() view, I get => Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'LocalizedStringKey'

Comment: working for me. Finally found the solution in SwiftUI context.

Answer (score 5):

@Tikhonov Alexander Does this mean that the bundle identifier must be specified in every Text element? Is there an easy way to set this for all Text elements or is there another way to change the Locale identifiert on the fly? Currently I am testing other languages with the preview by changing the Locale setting.

```
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
            .environment(\.locale, Locale(identifier: "ru"))
    }
```

Comment: This seems to have no effect when used on runtime.

Answer (score 1):

There is no **general** way to solve this(localization on the fly). This works only for the strings that your code displays.

Localization is tricky, it is more than strings, you have localized image assets, xibs (e.g. UIViewRepresentable), system images & system text, assets from 3 party libraries.

When starting to write a new app the first thing you care to localize is the text, but if you build your app with these "localization on the fly" solutions latter you might not be able to use it for all the assets that your app needs to localize.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LanguageManager-SwiftUI](https://github.com/Abedalkareem/LanguageManager-SwiftUI)

It's easy to use and you can get your app ready in a few steps.

1- Add a `Localizable.strings` file to your project.

2- Wrap your main view with `LanguageManagerView` and pass the default language that your app will run for the first time.

```swift
@main
struct ExampleApp: App {
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      // The default language when the app starts for the first time.
      // it can be the `deviceLanguage`, `ar`, `en`, or any language.
      LanguageManagerView(.deviceLanguage) {
        AppView()
          .transition(.slide) // The animation that will be happening when the language change.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

3 - To change the language you should change the `selectedLanguage` as below.

```swift
struct LanguageView: View {
  
  // MARK: - Properties
  
  @EnvironmentObject var languageSettings: LanguageSettings
  
  // MARK: - body
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("Select a language")
        .padding()
      Button("Arabic") {
        withAnimation {
          languageSettings.selectedLanguage = .ar
        }
      }
      .padding()
      Button("English") {
        withAnimation {
          languageSettings.selectedLanguage = .en
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For more details you can read the read me section for the library.

Comment: Your solution make my app enter on infinite loop!

Comment: @Basel 
Can you give more details about the issue? I'm using it in my app and it's working fine.

Comment: @AbedalkareemOmreyh I guess withAnimation has some issue in lower version. Did you tested it in ios14?